# Testing EJB with Arquillian I get "Please include at least 1 Deployable Container on your Classpath."

Tags: java, junit, ejb, jboss-arquillian, java-ee-8

I'm trying to test the following bean with Arquillian, but get an error saying that cannot find a deployable container:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    public int add1(int x) {
            return x + 1;
    }
    
}
```

The test class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.asset.EmptyAsset;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive; 
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;  
 
  
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)  
public class MySimpleBeanTest {

  @Inject  
  private MyBean bean; 

  @Deployment
  public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)   
        .addClass(MyBean.class)
        .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
  }

  @Test
  public void readManyTest() {
      int x = bean.add1(2);
      Assert.assertEquals(x, 3);
  }
  
}
```

And pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>visualbank-ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>visualbank-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-MR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svenkubiak</groupId>
            <artifactId>jBCrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- START Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-file-share</artifactId>
            <version>12.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- START testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.enterprise.concurrent-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>payara-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.2022.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- END testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HTTP client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- formula calculation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jexl3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- BankLoad uses guava BiMap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Utilized by several app modules to send emails -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Reads files in CSV format -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-container-test-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-core-impl-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-test-impl-base</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-spi</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>ejbModule</sourceDirectory>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>ejbModule</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>15</source>
                    <target>15</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I'm using JDK 15, Eclipse 2022-06 and Wildfly 26.0.1. When I run the test, I get:

> org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.ValidationException:
> DeploymentScenario contains a target (*DEFAULT*) not matching any
> defined Container in the registry. Please include at least 1
> Deployable Container on your Classpath.   at
> org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.throwNoContainerFound(DeploymentGenerator.java:244)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to make progress with arquillian. but i found a solution that works also with java 17 using openejb.

dependency in the pom:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.SP1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-MR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.svenkubiak</groupId>
            <artifactId>jBCrypt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- START Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j18-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- END Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-file-share</artifactId>
            <version>12.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- START testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise.concurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.enterprise.concurrent-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
   
        <!-- END testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HTTP client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- formula calculation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-jexl3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- BankLoad uses guava BiMap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>27.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Utilized by several app modules to send emails -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Reads files in CSV format -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-tomee</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

an the test class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.example1.MyBean;
import org.junit.Before;
Import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CiaoTest {
    
    private Context context;

    private EJBContainer ejbContainer;
    
    @Before
    public void init() throws NamingException {
        ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
        context = ejbContainer.getContext();
        context.bind("inject",this);
    }
    
    @EJB
    private MyBean myBean;
    
    @Test
    public void ciaoTest() {
        assertNotNull(myBean);
        int x = myBean.add1(2);
        assertEquals(x, 3);
    }
    
    @After
    public void destroy() {
        ejbContainer.close();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to use Arquillian as that's the standard for WildFly, any ideas how to fix the problem?

Comment: Try to open an issue on https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ARQ/issues/ARQ-2195?filter=allopenissues they can tell you if Java 15/17 is supported

Comment: I opened https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ARQ-2221